# beautiful soup - get text with many space character into datafame

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am looking for a solution to finish the following code:

```
import bs4
import requests
import pandas as pd

url="https://tradingeconomics.com"
soup=bs4.BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

head = soup.find_all('div', {'class' : 'col-md-7'})
ls = {
    'headline': [],
    'text': [],}

for text in head:
    td = text.text

    if len(td) > 1:
        print(len(td))
        print(td)
    #
        ls['headline'].append(td[0])
        ls['text'].append(td[1])

df = pd.DataFrame(ls)
```

I expect the headline and the text on the website to be in the dataframe `df`. I am not able to find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite simple, just narrow down your search using `.find()` as follows:

Find the class `col-md-7`. The "headline" is under the `a` tag. The "article" is under the class `headlines-description`.

```
import bs4
import requests
import pandas as pd


url = "https://tradingeconomics.com"
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")


ls = {
    "headline": [],
    "text": [],
}

for tag in soup.find_all("div", {"class": "col-md-7"}):
    headline = tag.find("a").get_text(strip=True)
    article = tag.find("span", class_="headlines-description").text

    ls["headline"].append(headline)
    ls["text"].append(article)

df = pd.DataFrame(ls)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
                               headline                                               text
0  Fed Signals Two Hikes by End of 2023  The Fed left the target range for its federal ...
```